# How to declare a symbol to reside at a specific address in Microsoft VIsual C compiler?

Tags: visual-c++, msvc12

I want to compile an independent binary which I'll then byte to byte copy in the context of another binary (probably using Hex Editor). I can specify the base by '/BASE' option but I wasn't able to find a way for me to say something like:

```
int var@0x30000; //only declare the symbol by its address in the host binary
```

Comment: There is no mechanism for this, the linker decides where stuff is placed and it doesn't have a way to nail anything down to a specific address.  You'll have to use an OS function, like VirtualAlloc(), and keep your fingers crossed that the address is not already in use.  If two processes need to agree about a memory location then use a memory-mapped file.  Beware that you are asking about a solution without describing the real problem, it is a very unusual one.

Comment: @HansPassant The idea is - I want to compile a part of another executable. I'll manually copy the content.

Answer (score 0):

To store part (or all) of one executable (or another arbitrary blob) inside another PE executable, you probably want to look into storing it as a binary resource, which you'll then read with [FindResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winbase/nf-winbase-findresourcea), [LoadResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648046.aspx), [LockResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648047.aspx), etc.

This also saves you from using a hex editor to embed the blob into the executable--you can use the normal build tools (resource compiler and linker) to handle embedding the data into the executable.